# A word to describe "class of" for summer camps

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage, expressions

In the same way that one would say "class of 2010" to describe the student body in a school for a given year, what word could I use to describe the "camper body" of a summer camp?

Comment: You mean like: newbies, second-years, and old-timers?  I expect each camp will develop its own terminology.

Comment: @GEdgar - no, I'm looking for a generic way to refer to all the campers as a whole, regardless of which camp it is.

Comment: @JasonBassford that might work. I thought there might be a more suitable word.

Comment: I'd have thought campers and camp organisers would have been very happy with "class of XXXX" even though everyone knew it wasn't a class.

Either way, what would be wrong with "Camp(ers) of… ", please?

Comment: possibly take a lead from the scouts and use the word 'participants' https://www.2019wsj.org/attend/participants/

Answer (score 1):

Another suggestion: How about "2010 cohort"?

Definitions [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cohort), [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/cohort), and [here](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/cohort.html).

Comment: Hi Larry, this isn't a bad *suggestion*, but it falls a bit short of being a *detailed and authoritative answer*, and has been flagged by the system as "low-quality because of its length and content." To avoid its deletion, you might like to [edit] your post to provide further detail such as a dictionary definition for "cohort". See also [answer]. :-)

Answer (score 0):

How about ‘class camp of 2010’. Or ‘class camps of 2010’ if multiple.

Where you borrow ‘class of’ which is already known as a commonly used format - and append ‘camp’ which I think, everyone will understand.

If you can’t or don’t want to use ‘class of’ then you could say ‘Summer camp of 2010’. Or ‘Summer Camps of 2010’ if multiple.

Comment: Hi Jelila, it's a good suggestion. However, I would switch it around to "camp class" instead of "class camp." 

It seems more grammatically correct this way, since the "camp" serves as an adjective describing the type of class.

I also really like "Summer camp of [year]". Maybe using "camp" isn't even necessary. Maybe it should just be "[Camp Name] - Summer '10".